# Binary file recreating on each request in DXA 2.2.16 java

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2, sites-9.5

I m using DXA 2.2.16 Java with SDL Tridion Sites 9.5. I have noticed when all binary files like css, javascript, images are recreating with each request in BinaryData folder. This is happening with both enabling and disabling cache inside cd_client_conf.xml file. It is impacting the performance of the website since on each request DXA is recreating all binary files. Please suggest a solution. Below is current cache setting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceConfig CacheEnabled="${CIL_CACHE_ENABLED:-true}"
               ConnectionTimeout="${CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:-10000}"
               CacheUri="ehcache.xml"
               CacheExpirationDuration="5" ServiceAvailabilityCheck="true"
               CacheProviderClass="com.sdl.web.client.cache.GeneralCacheProvider"
               CacheConnectionTimeout="${CACHE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:-10000">
    <!-- Specify your CIS Environment's Discovery Service URL below -->
    <DiscoveryService ServiceUri="${DISCOVERY_URL:-http://x.x.x.x:7082/discovery.svc}"/>

    <TokenService ClientId="cduser" ClientSecret="${cduserpassword:-encrypted:o/cgCBwmULeOyUZghFaKJA==}"/>
</ServiceConfig>
```

Comment: Abdul, can you confirm your current cache settings in the question?

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders added cache settings

Comment: A colleague shared this issue that sounded similar - I do note that this was resolved in 2.2.11 so maybe you can check the updates to the `refreshLocalization` method may be worth seeing if it's related? github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-java/issues/132